# Mail activity window

Tags: macos, mail.app

Often I am lost with what is Apple Mail doing or does it do anything.

So I have to open the Activity window to see what is going on.

In this example I was exporting a large mail box, but there was no indication on what is happening unless I open the Activity window.

[image: activity window]

I have the activity summary window open already, but it does not show details.

The question is, is there a way to have the Activity window pup up automagicaly when it is doing something. I can then close it knowing it is busy.

Answer (score 1):

You can show Mail Activity in the sidebar so that it's visible without you needing to open a separate window.

Click the **Show Mail Activity** button at the bottom of the Mail sidebar to open the drawer. The drawer will remain open in the corner and any activity will show in this area.

[image]

Comment: I have that one already open but it does not show any details which is what I prefer to see exactly what is going on like in the Activity window. If you have multiple activity going on that one does not show the individual, only overall status.

Comment: @Buscar What details does the window show that this drawer doesn't?